# How to find a file which contains dynamic substring at the end of its name

Tags: php, recursion, search, filesystems, glob

I want to create a php script which finds all files with name `favicon_323123.ico`. Of course, string `_323123` is not static.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
$filepath = recursiveScan('/public_html/wp-admin/');
$text = 'favicon' .*. 'ico'

function recursiveScan($dir) {
    $tree = glob(rtrim($dir, '/') . '/*');
    if (is_array($tree)) {
        foreach($tree as $file) {
            if (is_dir($file)) {
                //echo $file . '<br/>';
                recursiveScan($file);
            } elseif (is_file($file)) {
               if (strpos($file, $text) !== false) {
                   echo $file . '<br/>';
                   //unlink($file);
               }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#97228 may give a starting point.

Comment: Do you know the exact filename or just the pattern you are looking for?
In both cases the usage of the linux programm `find` may be a good alternative (e.g. vie `exec()`)

Comment: Regex: /favicon_[0-9]+\.ico$/

Comment: Ok, cool, good luck. `$text = 'favicon' .*. 'ico'` though is faulty, missing a `;`, missing a `.` before `ico` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

```
if (strpos($file, $text) !== false) {
```

To

```
if (preg_match( "/favicon_[0-9]+\.ico$/", $file )) {
```

The preg_match call, checks if the file is the file you're looking for or not.